# Office 365 API custom properties and file share

Tags: office365, onedrive

I'm testing new Office 365 API preview and creating app for uploading files to one drive. Everything is fine but I'm stacked with following issues:

All I wanna know (because Office 365 API is in preview) is:
Can I or can I not do the following staff with Office 365 API Preview:

- Sharing files with other users
- Change custom properties (not OOB ones)
- Upload files to specific folders on my One drive

Comment: ever manage to share a file to "anyone with the link"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I've got answer from Microsoft.

All in all, it is not possible with this version of API